# Set value in Map while debugging in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

While debugging I would like to change value in `HashMap` (map name: `params`). There is: "charset" -> "ISO-8859-1". When I try to `set value` (F2) and type: "charset" -> "UTF-8" then error message is: `Invalid expression : ->`. When I try to open "charset" -> "ISO-8859-1" then there is:

```
key = "charset" 
value = "ISO-8859-1"
```

but `set value` (F2) on  value = "ISO-8859-1" doesn't work, it's greyed out. When I open "value"="ISO-8859-1" then I see:

```
value={char[10]31444}
hash=20129143423
```

Is there a chance to change value in HashMap to set some different value instead of `ISO-8859-1`
 which already is there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open "Evaluate" window (Alt+F8) and type a normal code to put a new value into the map:

```
params.put("charset", "UTF-8")
```

Comment: This is correct answer. Additionally, the same can be also done in the "Set Value" field.

Comment: Yes, but it was a real nightmare when the map was deep inside under many other layered structures like lists, arrays, linkedHashMaps, etc... Until I realized that when you navigated to the desired level in the Debugger tab, you can just click "Evaluate" and the whole command for getting your structure will be pre-filled in the command window already, so you just need to add `.setValue(...)` or something like this! Huge time saver!